# rs.next() loop didn't function in oracle database data retrieving

Tags: java, database, oracle, resultset

Dbconn.java

```
import com.OracleCon;
public class Dbconn{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            OracleCon oraclecon = new OracleCon();
            oraclecon.callmethod();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Ex e"+e);
        }
    }
}
```

OracleCon.java

```
package com;

import java.lang.NullPointerException;
import java.sql.*;

public class OracleCon{

    String JDBC_DRIVER="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    String db_URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL";
    String username="SYSTEM";
    String password="root";
    Connection conn = null;

    public OracleCon() {
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(db_URL,username,password);
            if(conn!=null){
                System.out.println("Database connected");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Problem in connecting datbase");
            }
        }catch(SQLException se){
            System.out.println("Error occured " + se.toString());

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void callmethod() throws SQLException {

        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_URL,username,password);
        try{
            Statement stmt = null;
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "select USERID from userdetails";
            System.out.println(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            System.out.println("Result set finished "+rs);
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString("USERID"));
            }
            rs.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            System.out.println("SQL ex"+se);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Ex e"+e);
        }
        finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    public void closeConnection(){
        try{
            if(conn!=null){
                conn.close();
            }
        }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The database is successfully connected and the rs is holding some object which is shown by Sysout statement above rs.next(). But the problem is it is not entering the while(rs.next()), I tried it by printing some name inside that loop, even that Sysout is not printing. I dont know what is wrong with my code. It works for Mysql but it's not working for oracle database.

Comment: Perhaps, you inserted the records in a different DB session and forgot to `COMMIT` it?

Answer (score 0):

In your Oracle database, `select USERID from userdetails` isn't returning any rows. Confirm this by changing the query to `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`, which will return a single row. Then, investigate what the difference is between your MySQL and Oracle databases.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your result set is not having any record in it. Since rs.next() is returning false on its first invocation, it means it does not have any rows in it. Look at the ResultSet documentation-
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Connect to your database and verify if there are rows in the table.
ResultSet should work fine independent of underlying database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way you will come to know whether you resultset contains rows or not

```
if (!resultSet.isBeforeFirst() ) {  
  //this returns false if the cursor is not before the first record or if there are
  // no rows in the ResultSet.
 System.out.println("No data"); 
} 
else{
do {
    //your logic after fetching the data from the resultset
 } while (resultSet.next());
}
```